# I get this error: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). when I try to get the MAE and MSE of my models

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When my friend runs the code, it's fine and he gets the MSE and MAE values but when I run the exact code, I get that error.

```
df_month2['forecast'] = best_model.predict(start=0, end=489)

# MSE
mean_squared_error(y_true=df_month2['Close'],
                  y_pred=df_month2['forecast'])
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-8abe9e64cc5e> in <module>
      2 
      3 # MSE
----> 4 mean_squared_error(y_true=df_month2['Close'],
      5                    y_pred=df_month2['forecast'])

D:\x\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

D:\x\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py in mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, multioutput, squared)
    253 
    254     """
--> 255     y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
    256         y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
    257     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

D:\x\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput, dtype)
     84     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     85     y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False, dtype=dtype)
---> 86     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False, dtype=dtype)
     87 
     88     if y_true.ndim == 1:

D:\x\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

D:\x\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    642 
    643         if force_all_finite:
--> 644             _assert_all_finite(array,
    645                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    646 

D:\x\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
     94                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     95             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 96             raise ValueError(
     97                     msg_err.format
     98                     (type_err,

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I hope you guys can help me with this issue because on other machine this error does not appear but it does appear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check very well if you don't have the nan values in your inputs

```
import numpy as np
np.isnan(df_month2['Close']).sum()
np.isnan(df_month2['forecast']).sum()
```

if one of them give you a value more than 0, so have the nan values in your inputs and your
have to try to drop them or replace them by other numeric values.
you can use this statement for example :

```
data[np.isnan(data)] = 0.0
```